# Add MIDI Events to Clock - Java

Tags: c#, java, midi, clock

I am creating a simple MIDI application in C# with an [open source library](http://code.google.com/p/midi-dot-net/) that allows the user to specify a channel, pitch and velocity and add them to a Clock. This clock can then play all the notes in the sequence that they were added.

Everything works great and now I am in the process of creating a Java version of the application, the only trouble I seem to be having is that I can't find any simple tutorial or explanation of how the clock system works within MIDI Java.

Does the Clock exist in Java Sound Framework or is this something I will have to implement myself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a long time since I've touched the Java Midi stuff, but in general, to programmatically build a MIDI, you need to do the following steps.

Assuming `import javax.sound.midi;`:

1. You need to create a `Sequencer` object:

   ```
   Sequence seq = new Sequence(Squence.PPQ, 500000);
   ```
2. Next, you need to create a `Track` object (one per channel or one for everything, it's up to you):

   ```
   Track track = seq.createTrack();
   ```
3. Now, you can add events to it:

   ```
   track.add(new MidiEvent(new ShortMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, 0, 60, 127), 0));
   track.add(new MidiEvent(new ShortMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF, 0, 60, 127), 1000));
   //etc.
   ```
4. When you're done that, you can then play the `Sequence` like normal!

Check out the docs here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?javax/sound/midi/MidiSystem.html

Comment: For some reason using ShortMessage.NOTE_ON comes up with an error saying it can't be recognised.